# Select specific items from generator

Tags: python, generator

Given a generator object, I want to be able to iterate only over the elements with defined indices. However, I have experienced that when the generator yields "heavy" items (memory-wise), the loading of each item takes a considerable time compared to the case when iteration is performed on every element in the original order. Here is a minimal example, where in my real situation, I have no direct access to the generator function (i.e. `mygen` cannot be modified).

```
import itertools
import numpy as np 

def mygen(n):
    
    for k in range(n):
        yield k 
        

mygenerator=mygen(10)

indices_ls=[0,5,8]
mask      =np.zeros(10,dtype=int)
mask[indices_ls]=1

compressed_generator=itertools.compress(mygenerator, mask)
for i in compressed_generator:
    print(i)
```

This minimal code does the trick, because only selected elements are printed. But, is there a way to do this without using the `compressed_generator`, i.e. by iterating directly over the original generator, but getting ONLY the specified indices? Recall that the generator function (`mygen`)cannot be modified.

Comment: No. The only thing `compress` does is internally fetch and ignore values that don't pair with a given index. An arbitrary generator provides no access to its values except via the iterator protocol.

Comment: The only work around would be if your generator supports using `send` to specify the index of the next value to generator.

Comment: How can I know if a generator supports that? Also, any clue why iterating over the compressed version yields a significant drop in performance? The key here is to avoid loading all elements of the generator if possible.

Comment: You would have to check the documentation for the generator. (Note, I don't expect it to be an option. I can imagine how to implement such a generator, but I don't recall ever seeing one that *does*.) It's slower because it not only has to iterate over the generator normally but also check each index to see if it's one of the requested values. It's not something that's intended to speed up your code, it just abstracts away the filtering of a generator.

Comment: `compress` is basically just `def compress(itr, mask): for (i, x) in enumerate(itr): if  mask[i]: yield x`.

Comment: Generators are built around the concept of `yielding` the `next` element. The generator itself has no concept of how many elements there are, and so can't skip elements or seek specific elements. That's kinda the point of them. If you want an optimisation, you're going to have to specify your exact situation, not an abstract description. There may be options that don't use generators.

Comment: What do you mean with *"the loading of each item takes a considerable time compared to the case when iteration is performed on every element in the original order"*? How much time? I don't see you doing anything with a non-original order.

Comment: *"compressed version yields a significant drop in performance"* - How much?

Comment: What's the real situation like? How many elements does the generator yield, how many indices do you want?

Comment: Can you show an actual [mre], i.e., which actually reproduces the performance drop?

Comment: why can't you simply: `for x in my_gen(10): if x in indices: print(x)`

Comment: @OneMadGypsy That confuses elements with indices and will be slow if `indices` is large.

Comment: @KellyBundy- I don't really see a way around it. The OP has to use the generator and their conditions are in a list. No matter what, they are going to have to loop, and indices will be the condition. The question seems to be more "How do I make a bad system less terrible while keeping all parts of the bad system?". Why not just loop over the indices and get rid of the generator altogether?

Comment: @OneMadGypsy Around what? The bug or the quadratic runtime? Neither is necessary, you introduced both. *"Why not [...] get rid of the generator altogether?"* - That doesn't sound like you've read the question.

Answer (score 2):

If the generator takes a long time loading items, there is nothing much you can do from the outside to improve performance.

If you want to process specific indexes, iterate through the list of indices and skip over unwanted values.  You can place that in a function of your own to make it easier to use:

```
def xslice(gen,indices):
    skipFrom = 0                    # base for skipping unwanted 
    for i in indices:
        for _ in range(i-skipFrom): # skip to previous iteration
            next(gen)
        yield next(gen)             # next after skipping is wanted
        skipFrom = i+1
        
for i in xslice(mygen(10),[0,5,8]):
    print(i)

0
5
8
```

*This will also stop iterating after processing the highest indice which may save a bit of time*

If you have access to the source code of that generator function you may find that it is designed to allow using send() to control its progression.  This will depend on that generator's implementation but there could be a way to work around the problem with .send() if you are lucky.

For example, here's a variant of the toy generator that accepts a sent value to reposition the progression (the telltale sign of .send() support is that it uses the value returned from the yield statement):

```
def mygen(n):
    k = 0
    while k<n:
        skipTo = yield k
        k = k+1 if skipTo is None else skipTo
```

You could leverage this to skip to the desired indices (although the first one is tricky because you can't send() before the first iteration).

```
gen     = mygen(10)
indices = [0,5,8]
for i in indices:
    if i==indices[0] and i>0:
        next(gen)
    if i>0: gen.send(i-1)
    value=next(gen)
    print(value)
```

Comment: I'd say `islice` is good, just not the way you used it. And the name `skip` seems rather misleading/confusing, what's your explanation for calling it that?

Answer (score 1):

One solution might be to *"patch"* the function the generator is using (in this case `range()`, but in your original code you need to patch your functions):

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager


def mygen(n):
    for k in range(n):
        yield k

@contextmanager
def patch_range():
    def my_range(x):
        yield 0
        yield 5
        yield 8

    try:
        original_range = __builtins__.range
        __builtins__.range = my_range
        yield
    finally:
        __builtins__.range = original_range

with patch_range():
    for i in mygen(10):
        print(i)
```

Prints:

```
0
5
8
```

Comment: It is an interesting workaround, but unfortunately I cannot modify any of the functions the generator is using; this is an object loaded from an external library.

Comment: @Zarathustra Maybe you can patch the function in external library (and load only the objects you need...)